# Load img after load previous image with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, load

i want load img after load previous image

```
    <img src="~/images/bg1.jpg" id="img1" class="bgM" />
    <img src="~/images/bg1.jpg" id="img2" class="bgM" />
    <img src="~/images/bg3.jpg" id="img3" class="bgM" />
    <img src="~/images/bg4.jpg" id="img4" class="bgM" />
```

i want to load img2 when img1 has finished loading.

first #img1 loaded then load #img2
after load #img2 load #img3
then #img4

Comment: u should use jquery lazy load plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want an image to load, you can't specify its `src` attribute.  Instead, use an attribute of `data-src` and use JavaScript to write the `src` only when the previous image has loaded (or failed to load):

```
$(function () {
    $(".bgM").on("load error", function () {
        loadImg($(this).next(".bgM"));
    });
    loadImg($(".bgM").first());
});

function loadImg(img) {
    img.prop({ src: img.data("src") });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NKLTE/2/

Answer (score 0):

use this 
http://jsfiddle.net/c2N5U/
css

```
img {display:none;}
```

in js

```
$(window).load(function(){
       $("img").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);
    });
 });
```

Comment: sorry i made a mistake

Comment: i want loading img2 when loading img1 is finish

Comment: Your code is working because you add the same image but in his code, he loads different images.

Comment: than use window load function

Comment: Yes but it's not what he wants. He wants the image is loaded to load the next, not the window is loaded...

Answer (score 0):

If you include your images in a div like that :

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="~/images/bg1.jpg" id="img1" class="bgM" />
    <img src="~/images/bg1.jpg" id="img2" class="bgM" />
    <img src="~/images/bg3.jpg" id="img3" class="bgM" />
    <img src="~/images/bg4.jpg" id="img4" class="bgM" />
</div>
```

You can use this jquery code which really wait that an image is loaded to load the next :

```
function loadImage(i) {
    $('<img src="~/images/bg'+i+'.jpg id="img'+i+'" class="bgM" />').appendTo("#images").fadeOut(0).fadeIn(500, function(){
        if (i < 4) {
            loadImage(i + 1)
        }
    })
}

loadImage(1)
```